# Android - Using a custom image for GoogleMap overlay

Tags: android, google-maps

How to use a custom image as an overlay for GoogleMap?

I am in an android pilgrimage of making an app which uses a custom map for a specific place (Yeah.. Because google satelite view isn't good enough..).

Do I have to use Drawable?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [GroundOverlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/groundoverlay) with which you can set an image onto a map based off Lat/Lng coordinates.

Here's the sample code on how to add the overlay:

```
LatLng NEWARK = new LatLng(40.714086, -74.228697);

GroundOverlayOptions newarkMap = new GroundOverlayOptions()
        .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.newark_nj_1922))
        .position(NEWARK, 8600f, 6500f);
map.addGroundOverlay(newarkMap);
```

If you need a larger overlay, then it may be better to use a [TileOverlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/tileoverlay)

Comment: A bit unrelated question : If I were to create a project of a parking system, should I use an overview image and adding geolocation library, or use googlemaps image and ground overlay that small part of map? Is there any other info I should have provided? Let me know :D